# How to list all changed files in a particular branch?

Tags: git

I have created one branch xyz from master. I have done approximately 1000 commits and probably modified 20 files in xyz branch. Now I want to list all the files which I have modified in xyz branch.

Following command lists files modified in both branches.

```
git diff --name-only master...xyz
```

Comment: drop the `...` : `git diff --name-only master xyz`

Comment: According [git diff documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_description) the `master...xyz` syntax for **diff** (not the `log`) should give just what you needed. If you think it gives you wrong result, could you provide a minimal example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that `git diff` compares two specific commits.<sup>1</sup>  No matter what arguments you give it, it's *still* going to choose two specific commits, and compare those two.<sup>2</sup>

What this means is that to get `git diff` to show you what you have done in some branch, you must pick two commits within that branch: one to call a "starting point" and one to call an "ending point".  If you choose to do this, it usually helps to draw the commit graph.  You can do this manually, or use `git log --oneline --graph` to help out.  (A nice way to see this graph for your two branches in comparison with each other is `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --boundary master...xyz`.)  Another way is to try drawing your graph yourself, which can let you represent it more compactly, or to use `gitk` or some other graphical viewer that will draw the graph.

If there is a single *merge base* commit between the tip commit on `master` and the tip commit on `xyz`, then:

```
git diff --name-only master...xyz
```

will compare (and list the names of files modified) that particular merge base, vs the tip-most commit of branch XYZ.  That is, if the graph looks something like:

```
          o--o--o--o--...--o--Z   <-- master
         /
...--o--*
         \
          F--G-...--X             <-- xyz
```

then `*` is the merge base commit, `Z` is the tip commit on `master`,<sup>3</sup> `X` is the tip commit on `xyz`, and `git diff master...xyz` will compare commit `*` vs commit `X`.  (By contrast, `git diff master..xyz`—note the two dots instead of three, here—will compare commit `Z` vs commit `X`.)

That said, given that `git diff --name-only master...xyz` is not showing you what you want, you might want `git log --name-only master..xyz` (probably also with `--oneline`; I see [gucce added this as a comment as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697282/how-to-list-all-changed-files-in-a-particular-branch#comment66695839_39697786)), to show you what happens in *each* commit that is in `xyz` that is not also in `master`.  That is, given the above graph, this will diff commit `*` against commit `F`, then `F` against `G`, and so on up to the comparison against `X`.  Note that this is using `git log`'s built-in ability to diff each commit against its parent.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>It can also compare one commit to the index, or one commit to the work-tree, or the index to the work-tree.  In another mode it can be used to compare two specific files, either or both of which need not be stored in the repository at all, but that's even more different from the way you want to use it.

<sup>2</sup>This, too, is a bit of an overstatement: by giving `git diff` more than one pair of commits, you can get it to produce what it calls a *combined diff*.  This is normally used for merge commits, to show points where the merged contents differ from all parent commits, i.e., where a merge conflict was resolved by choosing something other than "what was in one branch".  But this, too, goes quite a bit in the wrong direction, compared to what you want to achieve.

<sup>3</sup>I had this as `T`, for tip-of-master, for a moment, but then realized that `T` is alphabetically between `F` and `X`.  `X` is for `xyz`, so I changed `T` to `Z` here so that it comes after `X`.  The general idea is that we're not interested in most of the commits exclusively on `master`, except for the tip-most one that the name `master` selects.

<sup>4</sup>If any of the commits in the `F`-through-`X` chain is a *merge* commit, `git log` won't even bother to diff it at all unless you add some additional options.  That is, `git log` skips over merges when it comes time to diff them, unless you either ask for combined diffs (`-c` or `--cc`) or to split merges (`-m`).  All three of these options have drawbacks as well, so your best bet is to work with a no-merges situation in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by @torek, the `git diff` command ignores the dot notation completely.

Therefore, the following command should lead to the desired results:

```
git log --oneline --name-only develop..xyz | sort | uniq
```

Which prints out something like this, with the modified files at the end:

```
0871be6 commit 1
9caad09 commit 2
bb714f0 commit 3
...
path/to/file1
path/to/file2
path/to/file3
path/to/file4
```

Notice, there are only **two** dots. This means, take into consideration all revisions which are in `xyz` but not in `develop`.

Using three dots uses all revisions which are exclusively in one of the two branches, but not in both.

Reference: https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges

Comment: I tried this too, It lists files even which I have not modified in xyz branch.

Comment: This is correct for all *other* Git commands, particularly `git log`, but not for `git diff`, which (ab)uses the two and three dot notations for other purposes. In particular `git diff X...Y` means `git diff $(git merge-base X Y) Y`, while `git diff X..Y` means `git diff X Y`. `git diff` will not look at intermediate commits. (The triple-dot notation is also susceptible to another issue if there is no merge base, or if there are multiple merge bases.)

Comment: Maybe you have accidentally added a new line at the end, or changed line endings. To verify what has been changed for a specific file in your `xyz` branch you can use `git log -p develop..xyz  -- path/to/file`. This will list all the commits from `xyz` (but not `develop`) which have modified `path/to/file` and the diff itself (`-p` is for 'patch'). Try this on one of the files you think you have not modified.

Comment: As @torek has pointed out. `git diff` does not work correctly with the dot notation. In this case I would suggest `git log --oneline --name-only develop..xyz | sort | uniq` which will first list the shortened commit hashed and messages, and after that all the files which have been changed.

Comment: Thanks people! Instead of `--online` I'm using `--pretty=""` to only display files: `git log origin..HEAD --name-only --pretty="" | sort | uniq`